# C# Try to cast strings from a list of types

Tags: c#, types, casting

So I have two lists of equal length, a list of strings and a list of types. Since want to verify if the strings can be converted to their respective type specified in the second list. If this is not possible I want to throw an exception.

So, imagine something like this:

```cs
var strings = new List<string>(){"hi","123","542342342424423","5.1"};
var types = new List<Types>(){typeof(string),typeof(int),typeof(long),typeof(double)};
```

So I want to check if:

```
hi can be converted to a string
123 can be converted to an int
542342342424423 can be converted to a long
5.1 can be converted to a double
```

I thought doing this something like this:

```cs
for (var index = 0; index < 4; index++)
{
    var str = strings[index];
    var @type = types[index];

    // Attempt something like this
    if(!str is @type)
        throw new Exception()
}
```

However this doesn't work because `@type` is not a constant expression.
I do not necessarily need to casted values I just need a verification (true/false) if they can be converted or not.
How can I solve this?

Comment: **Why** do you want this feature? What will it enable you to do?

Comment: @mjwills I am writing a type checker for which I need exactly what I described above. I am given a string and a type and I need to validate if the string can be casted in said type.

Comment: You can simplify this by determining how to do it with one type. Write a method that takes a string and a type and determines if it can be converted. If you can do it with one, you can do it with multiple. But when you write that one function, my guess is you're going to see that's where the problem is. This doesn't sound helpful, but this is the sort of problem that's best solved by not having it in the first place. In other words, step back, look at what you want to accomplish, and find another way that doesn't involve doing this at all.

Comment: Do all of the target types implement [IConvertible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iconvertible)? If so I would use `Convert.ChangeType` and be done with it. I wouldn't spend any more time thinking about "what if" for types you don't have to deal with yet. Don't cross a bridge you haven't come to.

Comment: @ScottHannen It's mainly primitives and a few types such as DateTime and BigInteger

Comment: Another valid approach: Don't check. Just do the conversion. If it doesn't work it will throw an exception. If an exception is thrown because the inputs are invalid, catch it and ensure that the rethrown exception clearly indicates that the inputs are invalid. Otherwise you're converting twice - once to make sure that you can convert, and again to convert. It seems like the result would be exactly the same, so why check twice?

Answer (score 5):

In c# a string is not equivalent to it's type (compared to javascript for instance). If you want to know if a string can be cast to int you have to call int.TryParse() and see if it succeed.

This means you won't probably be able to generalize the way you expect.

Edit:

I wrote a kind of generic way of doing it as long as you can define a method for every type you may encounter

```
     var strings = new List<string>(){/* whatever strings */};
     var typeTesters = new List<Func<string, bool>>
     {
         text => int.TryParse(text, out _),
         text => double.TryParse(text, out _),
         text => long.TryParse(text, out _),
     };

     for (var index = 0; index < 4; index++)
     {
         var str = strings[index];
         var tester = typeTesters[index];

         // Attempt something like this
         if (!tester(str))
             throw new Exception();
     }
```

As given in other answers you can provide a generic test for every basic types by using Convert.ChangeType and provide your own function for custom types.

Comment: I am pretty sure there is some generic approach for this. I can't imagine having a giant switch for every possible type...

Comment: @BrunoBelmondo I thinking it might be best to just have a ValueConverter class for all possible types instead. I mean, the `Convert.ChangeType()` approach works for primitives, but imagine non-primitive types like `Date`, `Time` ..

Comment: Usually for complex types in C# we use Json. You can try Newtonsoft.JSON.

Comment: `Convert.ChangeType` does work with `DateTime`. It works with anything that implements `IConvertible`.

Comment: @ScottHannen This might be the best choice then

Comment: @ScottHannen The only issue that can come up are comma separated lists. So for example the value would be `10,20,30,40` and the type is `List<int>` as this is also possible. I doubt the `ChangeType` can deal with this. The list could be also of a different type such string, float, DateTime etc ..

Answer (score 4):

I hope I understood you query correctly. You could make use of [Convert.ChangeType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.changetype?view=netframework-4.8) for the purpose

```
var strings = new List<string>(){"hi","123","542342342424423","5.1"};
var types = new List<Type>(){typeof(string),typeof(int),typeof(long),typeof(double)};

foreach(var item in strings.Zip(types,(x,y)=> new {Value = x, Type = y }))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{Convert.ChangeType(item.Value,item.Type)} can be converted to {item.Type}");
}
```

If you need to throw a Custom Exception, you could wrap the print statement within a try catch.

For example,

```
foreach(var item in strings.Zip(types,(x,y)=> new {Value = x, Type = y }))
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{Convert.ChangeType(item.Value,item.Type)} can be converted to {item.Type}");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            // Do the required processing
        }

    }
```

Sample Output

```
hi can be converted to System.String
123 can be converted to System.Int32
542342342424423 can be converted to System.Int64
5.1 can be converted to System.Double
```

Comment: This is good for basic types but can't be generalized for types not directly handled by Convert.ChangeType. Good Idea anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yeah it works fine for primitives, but as soon as we want to convert to non-primitives problems come up. Maybe a Converter class would be a better approach?

Answer (score 1):

**Alert:** This is nothing but a combination of both Bruno's and Anu's solution.

As I preferred using own conversion checker, I just made a small change.

**SOLUTION:**

```
try {
  var strings = new List<string> () { "hi", "123", "542342342424423", "5.1" };
  var types = new List<Type> () { typeof (string), typeof (int), typeof (long), typeof (double) };
  foreach (var s in strings.Zip (types, (x, y) => new { Value = x, DataType = y }))
    if (!IsValidType (s.DataType.ToString (), s.Value)) throw new Exception ($"{s.DataType} is not a valid type for {s.Value}");
} catch (Exception e) {
  Console.WriteLine (e.ToString ());
}
```

**CONVERSION CHECKER:**

```
static bool IsValidType (string data_type, string value) {
  switch (data_type) {
    case "System.Int32": return int.TryParse (value, out _);
    case "System.Int64": return long.TryParse (value, out _);
    case "System.Double": return double.TryParse (value, out _);
    case "System.String": return true;
    default: return false;
  }
}
```